# android dashed border with padding

Tags: android, border, stroke

i have a RadioGroup [image: RadioGroup]
I would like to add a dashed stroke(boder?) with some padding.

The background of Radio Buton is

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation"/>
    <item >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
            <stroke android:color="#ffffff"
                    android:dashGap="5dp"
                    android:dashWidth="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The second item - is my attemp to draw dashed line.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding `android:width="1dip"` to your `<stroke>` tag.

Comment: Do you know how to add padding? <padding android:bottom="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"/> does not work...

Answer (score 27):

I think this will help you.

try this.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke
                android:dashGap="5dp"
                android:dashWidth="5dp"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#0000FF" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```